# Used memory in bytes. Linux Heap Block size

Tags: linux, heap-memory, valgrind, block

I'm using the valgrind to know how many bytes my linux application is using.
So, the Valgrind summary show me the number of heap block used. Thus, i'd like to know what is the size of these blocks to know the size of the heap.

here the Heap Summary of the Valgrind:

```
==2604== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2604==     in use at exit: 4,828,441 bytes in 1,416 blocks
==2604==   total heap usage: 389,448,458 allocs, 389,447,042 frees, 4,664,484,349 bytes allocated
==2604==
```

I can't simply do block/bytes because the last block isn't necessarily all allocated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `--leak-check=full` and `valgrind` will show a detailed summary of blocks by call-stack. You may need to add also `--show-reachable=yes` if the blocks are still reachable. From there, you can use some simply math to know the average size of each type of block.

```
==15210== 46,622 bytes in 1,626 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==15210==    at 0x4022724: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==15210==    by 0x80562A1: (within /bin/ls)
==15210==    by 0x80563D1: (within /bin/ls)
==15210==    by 0x8053B84: (within /bin/ls)
==15210==    by 0x804F686: (within /bin/ls)
==15210==    by 0x804FAEB: (within /bin/ls)
==15210==    by 0x406F02B: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.6.1.so)
==15210==
```

That above are blocks of average size:

```
$ echo $((46622/1626))
28
```

Answer (score 1):

On most machines (I'm pretty sure all i386 and x86_64 machines) memory is managed in 4096 byte blocks.

Comment: Yep.  Most architectures can have 4k pages in their page table entries . IIRC, ARM can actually have 1k (depricated), 4k, 16k, or 64k.  x86 can have 4k or 4MB (see Linux hugetlb).  The advantage is fewer TLB misses while the disadvantage is wasting space.